# After a Capybara failed scenario output screen shot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I want to output a screen shot of the page after a failed scenario.

I'm using capybara, rspec and launchy - my gemfile has

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'launchy'
end
```

I've seen various suggestions which include the following code

```
After do |scenario|
  save_and_open_page if scenario.failed?
end
```

So, I've created a spec\support\env.rb file into which I've put this code (and that is all, there is nothing else in that file). Now when I run

```
bundle exec rspec
```

I get

```
C:/Working/x/spec/support/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `After' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

If I comment out the lines in env.rb, then the tests run as I'd expect.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Versions:

- rails 4
- rspec 2.14.1
- capybara 2.1.0
- launchy 2.3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try wrapping it in a Rspec.configure block, something like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after { |example_group| save_and_open_page if example_group.exception }
end
```

Comment: I changed it to be: 

`RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after { |scenario| save_and_open_page if scenario.failed? }
end`

to get around the error `"undefined local variable or method 'scenario'"` but now I get `undefined method failed?`

Comment: Sorry, it made a typo error and not tried the solution. It seems that the after hook yields an ExampleGroup instead of an Example to the block, I edited my answer. Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: That's sorted it @ejosafat. I've actually ended up using save_page and used example_group.example.description to name the page so it is easy to see which scenario failed. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 4):

@ejosafat - extra "example." in you answer, so I used it as following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after { |example_group| save_and_open_page if example_group.exception }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem, you just need to add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'capybara-screenshot', :group => :test
```

All the instructions can be found here:- https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot